# Issue web scraping javascript website using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am having issues building a web scraper for this website which heavily uses javascript. The code I have is below:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

#Page 1
url1 = 'https://www.zalora.co.id/women/pakaian/atasan/?gender=women&dir=desc&sort=popularity&category_id=704&page=1'
browser.get(url1)
soup_1 = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html5lib')
page_script_1 = soup_1.findAll('script')[40].text

#Page 2
url2 = 'https://www.zalora.co.id/women/pakaian/atasan/?gender=women&dir=desc&sort=popularity&category_id=704&page=2'
browser.get(url2)
page_script_2 = soup.findAll('script')[40].text
soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html5lib')
page_script_2 = soup_2.findAll('script')[40].text
```

The desired output is the html of the 2 distinct pages (i.e. the value in **page_script_1** should be different from **page_script_2**)

HOWEVER, the output in both cases appears to be the same. Anyone know why?

(Note, I basically want to scrape the products on all the pages)

Comment: What I’ve found in the past is the information is being called from the server and if you can isolate that request you can get all of the related information in JSON. It might not be the case with this website. Hopefully that helps.